# Can a .deb package include sources that are to be compiled by dpkg?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I have a pkg with some c++ code. Currently I'm compiling some of the c++ code as binary, some as library, and I can ship and deploy it on other platforms.

However, I also have a driver there, which I can't cross compile due to its dependency on the kernel, which makes it so that every kernel might need a different binary.

So, what I want to have is a .deb where I will store the binary under /usr/bin (done), the library under /usr/lib (also done) and the driver source code under /opt/driver (I guess... Is this a legit place for that?)

Packing this is the easy part, since all I need to do is put it in my workspace, and call `dpkg-deb`. What I'm not sure about are two things

1. Is it legit to pack source code in a .deb? (In python terminology - is .deb a bdist(binary distribution) or also can be an sdist (source distribution))
2. If it is legit, how can I invoke the make commands? Can `dpkg / apt` do that for me? Or do I need to run `dpkg -i pkg` and then run `make`? [looking at [postinst](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/deb-postinst.5.html) but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go]

*I'm open to any kind of build system if it can solve this though I'm currently using cmake and would much prefer sticking to it*

---

My POC:

```
tree bla_x86_64
bla_x86_64
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   └── postinst
├── opt
│   └── bla.cpp
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── bla.bin
    └── lib
        └── bla.lib
```

```
cat bla_x86_64/DEBIAN/postinst 
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo hello world!
echo compiling $(ls /opt/bla.cpp)
echo cleanup
rm -rvf /opt/bla.cpp
```

```
$ dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group bla_x86_64/
dpkg-deb: building package 'bla' in 'bla_x86_64.deb'.
$ sudo dpkg -i bla_x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 407519 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bla_x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking bla (4.0) over (3.0) ...
Setting up bla (4.0) ...
hello world!
compiling /opt/bla.cpp
cleanup
removed '/opt/bla.cpp'
```

Comment: `dpkg` doesn't control anything.  If you are using DKMS properly you don't *need* a `make` command anywhere in the Debian file.  DKMS will automatically compile things where it has to - you shouldn't need to have any special `make` commands anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasWard I will need `dkms` command however, won't I? So, I'm still wondering if this is lefit, and if so, is there anyone who already done so (I used `make` in my question instead of `dkms` in order to simplify, but I guess it just complicated things...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically there is no such thing as "legitimate" or "illegitimate" content of a .deb file. You may pack anything you want in it.

A good place where to put your source code on the target system would be under `/usr/share/${packagename}`.

To have `dpkg` or `apt` invoke your make commands, just place them in your package's `postinst` script. Make sure that you declare as dependencies all the programs needed for the build process, such as `cmake`, `g++` and `binutils`, as well as the kernel headers, otherwise installation will fail on systems that happen to have no compiler installed. Also make sure you do proper error handling in your `postinst` script to avoid rendering the target system non-operational by installing a bad kernel module as a result of a failed compilation.

Note that this solves only half of your problem. In addition to compiling your driver for the kernel in use when your package is installed, you also need to make sure it is recompiled for the new kernel after each kernel update. The solution for this is DKMS, short for Dynamic Kernel Module Support. So you'll want to look into supporting DKMS in your .deb package, too.

Comment: Do you happen to know of pkgs that are doing such a thing? (ie calling make / dkms from postinst). I'm trying to find guys who did this before me and learn from them

Comment: Not offhand. If I wanted to find one I'd probably looking at Linux packages from hardware manufacturers who maintain out-of-tree drivers. Graphics adapters come to mind.

Comment: found it. Nvidia does interact with dkms in their postinst script

Comment: Do you know if such a `.deb` (i.e. only sources) should have a special `arch`? It should be arch-independent, but I'm not sure if this is possible

Comment: You can set `Architecture` to `all` to indicate an architecture independent package. A different approach, if your package really contains _only_ sources, would be to actually make it a source package.

Comment: I'm not sure. The sources in the package should be compiled into a driver. I read about source packages in https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage, but I think since [quote] "Sources are normally **not** installed", a binary package is best - it will contain the sources + the make command in `postinst` and installing the package will `make` the sources. What do you think?

Comment: If you consider making it a source package you should read up on the deb package build system. That will also clarify the meaning of the sentence you quote. Otherwise stick with `Architecture: all`.

Comment: Can you share a link? I found a lot of data, but none seems what I was looking for

Comment: I suggest you start at https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro and work your way up from there.